# Why scaling down the parameter many times during training will help the learning speed be the same for all weights in Progressive GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, gan

The title is one of the special things in [Progressive GAN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10196.pdf), a paper of the NVIDIA team. By using this method, they introduced that

> Our approach ensures that the dynamic range, and thus the learning speed, is the same for all weights.

In details, they inited all learnable parameters by normal distribution $N(0,1)$. During training time, each forward time, they will scale the result with **per-layer normalization constant from He's initializer**

I reproduced the code from [pytorch GAN zoo Github's repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch_GAN_zoo)

```
def forward(self, x, equalized):
    # generate He constant depend on the size of tensor W
    size = self.module.weight.size()
    fan_in = prod(size[1:])
    weight = math.sqrt(2.0 / fan_in)
    '''
    A module example:

    import torch.nn as nn
    module = nn.Conv2d(nChannelsPrevious, nChannels, kernelSize, padding=padding, bias=bias) 
    '''
    x = self.module(x)

    if equalized:
        x *= self.weight
    return x
```

At first, I thought the **He constant** will be $c = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n_l}}$ as [He's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf). Normally, $n_l > 2$ so $w_l$ can be scale up which lead to the gradient in backpropagation is increase as the formula in ProGan's paper $\hat{w}_i=\frac{w_i}{c}$ $\rightarrow$ prevent vanishing gradient.

However, the code shows that $\hat{w}_i=w_i*c$.

In summary, I can't understand why to scale down the parameter many times during training will help the learning speed be more stable.

I asked this question in some other communities e.g: StackOverflow, mathematics, Artificial Intelligent, and still haven't had an answer.

Please help me explain it clearly or in a mathematics way, thank you!

Comment: Smells like momentum.

Comment: @EngrStudent I am not sure, but they mention adaptive optimization such as Adam or RMSProp will try to scale the gradient with its std, and this method to avoid some bad things from that. I will add the quote to the question

Comment: They might be doing something related to the Robbins-Munro or Kiefer-Wolfowitz stochastic estimator. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729392 . Imagine the problem is higher than second order, then you aren't getting an exact root.  As you get closer to the minimum error you want a decrease in step-size so the error can be minimized.

Comment: I just read the abstract.  They might be using very rough grid, then iteratively refining it.  If you are going to solve a PDE (heat flow, navier stokes, ...) then you pick sample locations.  Many methods are n^2 or n^3 on number of points.  Part of the silent element in the complexity is how far the initial (typically random) guess is from truth.  If it is very close then compute is very fast.  What multiscale does is estimate on a crude grid, then use that for initial conditions for a finer and finer grid.  https://oaktrust.library.tamu.edu/handle/1969.1/ETD-TAMU-2991

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am working on several projects, and that information from your comments seem so fresh for me, it maybe takes time to understand all of them. However, I am still tracking this question so don't worry that I won't vote if you have a correct answer. I will read those documents and discuss with you later.